# Scene.getFocusOwner() returning null inseatd of node from Scene

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I have a JavaFX application. The way it works right now is it creates a `GridPane` and calls a function that takes an Arraylist of an object, where each object consists of a `Label`, `TextField`, and `Label` in that order. Said function adds all these nodes individually to the `GridPane` after which the `GridPane` is added to a `Scene`. Before I set up the `Stage`, I try to set up event handlers for all the `TextField` objects in a separate function. In there I try to get the `Textfield` in which the cursor is currently waiting, to decide what action a `Textfield` will take. I try to use Scene.getFocusOwner in a separate function to get the TextField currently selected but it always returns Null, when it should return an object that I can cast to `TextField` (even after the application has started). The relevant code is below:

```java
//How the start function looks
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Warehouse Form");
        ArrayList<FormRow> entryRows = new ArrayList<>();        
       //each array holds same number of Strings
        String defLabels[] = {"....", "....", ....};
        String defTextEntry[] = {"....", "....", ....};
        String defConfLabels[] = {"....", "....", ....};
       GridPane g = runDefaultForm(entryRows,defLabels, defTextEntry, defConfLabels);
       final Scene sc = new Scene(g,500,600);      
        setEntryEventHandlers(g, sc, primaryStage, entryRows);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Inside 'setEventEntryHandlers' function

```java
public void setEntryEventHandlers(GridPane g, Scene sc, Stage st, ArrayList<FormRow> formRows){
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        TextField curTextEntry = null;
        TextField nextTextEntry = null;
        Label curConfLabel = null;
        Label curLabel = null;
        //Iterate through every field and set event handler, goes down via row
        for(int i = 0; i < fieldsAdded; i++){
            curLabel = (Label)getNodeFromGrid(g, i, col);//Gets Label from coordinates
            curTextEntry = (TextField) getNodeFromGrid(g, i, col + 1);//Gets Entry Textfield from Coordinates
            nextTextEntry = (TextField)getNodeFromGrid(g,i + 1, col + 1 );//Gets the Next Text Entry from coordinates
            curConfLabel = (Label)getNodeFromGrid(g, i, col + 2);//
            //function call that contains Scene.getFocusOwner
            TextField tempFocus = getFocusFromGrid(g, sc, formRows, userSelectedCoordinates);
            if(tempFocus == null){
                System.out.println("TEXTFIELD IS NULL BABY");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("ALL IS GOOD");
            }
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

The function where Scene.getFocusOwner is called...

```java
    public TextField getFocusFromGrid(GridPane g, Scene sc, ArrayList<FormRow> rows, int[] v){

        Node tempNode = sc.getFocusOwner();
        //try to find the node in children of GridPane, it will never find it because it is null
        if(g.getChildren().contains(tempNode)){
            System.out.println("FOUND THIS");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("NOTHING WAS FOUND");
        }
        return (TextField)tempNode;
     
    }
```

So that call for Scene.getFocusOwner always returns null, I'm not even sure if I set all of this uuprightor if I can use the function call two functions deep (so to speak) from the start function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: I really can't figure out what you're trying to do, but the code you have here runs before the stage is even on the screen, so none of the nodes could have focus yet.  Generally something that looks for focus would run inside of an event handler, not in layout code.

Answer (score 1):

Just move `setEntryEventHandlers` so it's invoked after show:

```
primaryStage.setScene(sc);
primaryStage.show();
setEntryEventHandlers(g, sc, primaryStage, entryRows);
```

What you're doing is invoking setEntryEventHandlers when primaryStage is not yet a window, so focus will be null. For better results, you should invoke it on the primaryStage.onShown event: `primaryStage.setOnShown(e-> setEntryEventHandlers(g, sc, primaryStage, entryRows));` and after setting onShown handler, you show the stage and should work fine.